# How to use preg match in array?

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

If I have an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => |174|September|2001| 
            [1] => |Pengantar=Hello!!!!
            [2] => |Tema= Sami Mawon 
            [3] => |Tema_isi=meet you!!!
            [4] => |Kutip=people
            [5] => |Kutip_kitab=Efesus
            [6] => |Kutip_pasal=4
            [7] => |Kutip_ayat=28
            [8] => |Tema_sumber=Kiriman dari Maurits albert (romind@ )
            [9] => [[Kategori:e-humor 2001]]
        )
```

How can I get the value of Pengantar, Tema, Tema_isi etc?

Comment: Please clarify which values you want and the criteria for matching those values.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to loop over the array and use preg_match with a reference. 
Regex *something* like this (off the top of my head) would probably work:

```
/\|(.*?)=(.*?)|?/
```

Just use `preg_match('/\|(.*?)=(.*?)|?/', $subject[$x], $matches);` and `var_dump($matches);` to see the results.

Don't forget that the $matches array passed into the preg_match function is a reference to an array which you should instantiate first and that it will be overwritten in each loop cycle.

Comment: but i can't get the value like **hello!!!, sami mawon, meet you!!!, people** etc. thanks before.
sorry, i am beginner..

Answer (score 1):

just use array walk, a matching reg ex and a lambda function:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        '|174|September|2001|',
        'Pengantar=Hello!!!!',
        'Tema= Sami Mawon ',
        'Kategori:e-humor 2001',
            [...]
    )
);

$values = array();

array_walk($array[0],function(&$item1, $key) use(&$values) {
    if(preg_match('#[^=]=(.+)#',$item1,$match)){
        $values[] = $match[1];
    }
});

print_r($values);
```

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression can be like this, using the [named subpattern](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php#example-4303) of ["`preg_match()`"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):-

```
$a = array(
    array(
        '|174|September|2001|',
        '|Pengantar=Hello!!!!',
        '|Tema= Sami Mawon',
        '|Tema_isi=meet you!!!',
        '|Kutip=people',
        '|Kutip_kitab=Efesus',
        '|Kutip_pasal=4',
        '|Kutip_ayat=28',
        '|Tema_sumber=Kiriman dari Maurits albert (romind@ )',
        '[[Kategori:e-humor 2001]]',
    )
);
$pattern = '/(?<first>\w+)[:=](?<rest>[\d|\w|\s]+)/';
$matches = array();
foreach ($a as $_arrEach) {
    foreach ($_arrEach as $_each) {
        $result = preg_match($pattern, $_each, $matches[]);
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

You will find that the array key "`first`" satisfies your requirement.

The above will output as:-

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Pengantar=Hello
            [first] => Pengantar
            [1] => Pengantar
            [rest] => Hello
            [2] => Hello
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tema= Sami Mawon
            [first] => Tema
            [1] => Tema
            [rest] =>  Sami Mawon
            [2] =>  Sami Mawon
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tema_isi=meet you
            [first] => Tema_isi
            [1] => Tema_isi
            [rest] => meet you
            [2] => meet you
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Kutip=people
            [first] => Kutip
            [1] => Kutip
            [rest] => people
            [2] => people
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Kutip_kitab=Efesus
            [first] => Kutip_kitab
            [1] => Kutip_kitab
            [rest] => Efesus
            [2] => Efesus
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Kutip_pasal=4
            [first] => Kutip_pasal
            [1] => Kutip_pasal
            [rest] => 4
            [2] => 4
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => Kutip_ayat=28
            [first] => Kutip_ayat
            [1] => Kutip_ayat
            [rest] => 28
            [2] => 28
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tema_sumber=Kiriman dari Maurits albert 
            [first] => Tema_sumber
            [1] => Tema_sumber
            [rest] => Kiriman dari Maurits albert 
            [2] => Kiriman dari Maurits albert 
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => Kategori:e
            [first] => Kategori
            [1] => Kategori
            [rest] => e
            [2] => e
        )
)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the question of "which pattern", I suggest you take a look into [`preg_replace`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/preg_replace) which is able to operate on arrays directly.

```
$pattern = "...";
$matches = preg_replace($pattern, '\1', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question, but it looks like you want [`preg_filter`](http://php.net/preg_filter).

This function can perform a regex match and replace on an array, returning a new array containing only the replaced values of the matched items.